# Workarounds for quick add in Google Calendar?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I often get event information in Text format like this:

```
Fri 7:30 Live From the Spanish Ballroom: Gretchen Midgley
Fri 8pm Evelyn and her New Orleans Jazz Band - LIVE from NOLA
Sat 6:30 Movin' & Groovin'! Featuring Amy Johnson & Todd Yanacone
Sat 7pm The Salon: Quarantine Speakeasy (Oct 24th)
Sun noon Solo Jazz with Nils Andren!
Sun 2pm Performance and Fundraiser for Furloughed Knoxville Symphony Musicians
```

Entering this info into my Google Calendar by hand is onerous to say the least. There used to be a quick add but there is apparently a patent issue around this with Microsoft (?) so this was removed from Google Calendar and Gmail?

Workaround 1: Mac Calendar / Mac Mail (partial solution)

I have my Mac Calendar synced with Google Calendar. If I email myself this data there is partial detection of the event, and when I hover over the time I get an arrow I can click to add to my Mac Calendar, but it doesn't get the title right (it's) blank.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Learn how to use Google Calendar API, and you can write your own program in php, python, or a couple other choices.

It may take a while to get it right but longer term its worth it, and the knowledge you gain from doing it makes it even more worth it.

Comment: I'm a software engineer, and I suspect that the API requires you to send structured data, ie data that is already parsed into component parts for date, time, description etc. I'm looking for a method to take semi-structure data and have that parsed by a mature algorithm into structured data. It's not particularly hard to do, but it can be tricky, and I'd rather not spend my time on it. If I end up writing my one, I'll post it here.

Comment: It's not that hard to implement keyword searches.  Does it contain the word Jan,Feb,Mar ...It must be the month. should be followed by the date.    Sure it may not be perfect, but if your writing it yourself you can do whatever you want.  Does it contain Mon,Tue,Wed ... must be the date of the week. How about am or pm clearly part of the time.  It would definitely take extra time to implement, but I bet it can be done.